# C# Constructor & methods

Tags: c#

I am studying C# in detail so I got across a text that I can not understand. Can  anybody explain it to me.

The last paragraph is not understandable

[image]

Comment: Your image link isn't available

Comment: By "last paragraph" do you mean the one on the second page? If so, please copy and paste it **as text** into your question.

Comment: Yes, on the second page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say there was a (non-static) method in your class called `Bob`.

The last paragraph means that your expression (the `this (price, year.Year)` bit) can't call `Bob`.

If the `Bob` method was `static` then the expression **could** compile.

Let's look at an example:

```
public class Runner
{
    public static string Bob1()
    {
        return "Hi";
    }
    public static string Bob2()
    {
        return "Hi";
    }

    public Runner(string hello)
    {
        // Some logic here
    }

    public Runner() : this(Bob2()) { }
```

would compile, but:

```
public class Runner
{
    public static string Bob1()
    {
        return "Hi";
    }
    public static string Bob2()
    {
        return "Hi";
    }

    public Runner(string hello)
    {
        // Some logic here
    }

    public Runner() : this(this.Bob1()) { }
```

wouldn't. *This is because the first code block uses the `static` `Bob2` while the second code block uses the (non-static) `Bob1`.*

Comment: Thanks a lot the answer. I understood the concept.

Answer (score 1):

you  can do this to understand  more what he means in the last paragraph

```
  public class Wine
        {
            public decimal Price;
            public int Year;
            public static int wineCategory = 8;
            public int capturedCategory; 
            public int capturedCategory2; 
            public int vote;    
            public Wine(decimal price)
            {
                Price = price;
            }

            public Wine(decimal price, int year) : this(price)
            {
                Year = year;
            }

            public Wine(decimal price, DateTime year) : this(price, year.Year)
            {
            }

            public Wine(decimal price, DateTime year, int wineCategory) : this(price, year.Year)
            {
                capturedCategory = wineCategory; 
            }
            //in  this overload I  can use the static property 
            public Wine(decimal price, DateTime year, int wineCategory,int vote) : this(price, new DateTime(year.Year,1,1),Wine.wineCategory)
            {
                vote= vote;
            }
           // but I can't do this 
            public Wine(decimal price, DateTime year, int wineCategory,int vote) : this(price, new DateTime(year.Year,1,1),this.capturedCategory)
            {
                vote =vote;
            }


        }
```

**To resume**
You can do the following overload because the static fields are constructed before the instance so it's accepted and compiled correctly

```
 public Wine(decimal price, DateTime year, int wineCategory,int vote) : this(price, new DateTime(year.Year,1,1),Wine.wineCategory)
                {
                    vote= vote;
                }
```

But you can't do this

```
public Wine(decimal price, DateTime year, int wineCategory,int vote) : this(price, new DateTime(year.Year,1,1),this.capturedCategory)
                {
                    vote= vote;
                }
```

because you don't have the instance in the memory constructed yet

*is more like the egg and chiken which come first :)*

Comment: Thanks a lot the answer. I understood the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack! So constructor overloading is useful if you want to have *different* options to create an object from a class (like the wine object). 
The text says you can use expressions within the `: this(param a, param b) {` function. 
such as `Wine(decimal price, DateTime time) : this(price, time.year)`.

*Expressions* is here `time.year`, a function call from another object.
You may have learned, that you can call functions from your own object with `this.function()`. However, you can't call a function if you haven't instantiated it.

Example:

```
public class Wine
{
    private decimal price;
    private int year;
    public Wine (decimal p){price =p;}
    public Wine (decimal p, int y) : this(p){ year=y;}
    public Wine (decimal p, DateTime time) : this(p, this.getYear(time)){} //this is not possible
    public int getYear(DateTime time){return time;}
}
```

since the object is not created until every constructor is finished, you can't call a `this.` function (here the `this.getYear(time)` function) from your own class. However, static functions are possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot the answer. I understood the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The last paragraph basically says that you can't do this:

```
class Foo {
    public int I { get; }
    // some more properties...

    public Foo(int i) { 
        this.I = i; 
        // a few other properties are set here
    }
    public Foo() : this(GetBar()) {} // this line gives you an error

    public int Get5() {
        // Here is looks at some other properties of Foo and returns something based on that
    }
}
```

That line gives you an error because it's actually `this(this.Get5())`. As the book says, you can't use the `this` keyword to pass parameters to another constructor because at that point, the object hasn't been created properly yet. Just imagine that `Get5` needs the object to be initialised correctly to return an expected result.

However, static methods are OK because they belong to the type itself.

Comment: `However, static methods are OK because they belong to the class itself..` you mean the type itself .?

Comment: Thanks a lot the answer. I understood the concept.